# Unable to present modal view controller in didFinishWithResult

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to present Modal view controller in didFinishWithResult?

I have an iPad application with 3 views Home,Start and Login. Start and Login modal views can be launched using start and login buttons in home view.

If clicked on login button, after successful login operation (didFinishWithResult) in login view I am able to dismiss the login view and but i am not able to launch the start view. But the control stays back on home view.

I am not getting any error for the above scenario.

**Appdeligate.m :**

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

HomeViewController  * homeview=[[HomeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeview];

self.rootViewController = navigationController;
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
self.rootViewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
[self.window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Below is the method in the home view which Present the login modal view

**Presenting Login Modal View**

```
LoginViewController * vc1 = [LoginViewController loginViewControllerWithNavBar:YES]; 
vc1.boxLoginDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
```

> Note : LoginVeiwController is Modal view controller which is presented
>   by HomeViewController. Is it right way to launch/present another modal
>   view controller (start controller) by dismissing LoginVeiwController
>   as below. Because whenever the LoginVeiwController dismissed the control stays back on HomeVeiwContrller rather than launching/presenting StartViewController:

**Home View** :

Below is the method in the home view which will dismisses the login view on successful login and tries to launch the start view.

```
- (void)loginViewController:(LoginViewController *)loginViewController didFinishWithResult:(LoginResult)result {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    startview = [[[startViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:startview animated:YES];

}
```

**If I present the StartView directly on button click, it launches nicely, but not on didFinishWithResult**

Comment: `- (void)loginViewController:(LoginViewController *)loginViewController didFinishWithResult:(LoginResult)result` seems like a delegate method.  Are you it's delegate?

Comment: That doesn't answer my second question though.  Are you the delegate of the caller of this method?

Comment: yes it is the delegate of the caller method

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's about the animation. While the previous controller is dismissing,

```
 [self presentModalViewController:startview animated:YES];
```

is called.

You can verify my guess by setting the animation to NO. Or directly use my suggestion to see if it works.

If I am correct, you can set them back to YES.
Besides, instead of directly calling the

```
[self presentModalViewController:startview animated:YES];
```

You can try:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(showController) userInfo:nil repeats:No];

 - (void)showController {
    [self presentModalViewController:startview animated:YES];
 }
```

edit:

I finally found out how I solve this similar problem before:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                     animations:^{
                            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                     } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"];
                     VideoConfirmViewController *videoConfirmCon = [[VideoConfirmViewController alloc]initWithFileURL:path];
                     [self presentModalViewController:videoConfirmCon animated:YES];
                 }
];
}
```

Comment: Maybe u can try again with a higher Time interval . 0.5 may not be enough for dismissing .

Comment: Even if I increase Time Interval to 6.0f, the Login modal view dismissed and stayed back on Home View. Did not navigate to StartView. Please recheck my question I have edited it.

Comment: I don't know if you have solved your problem. But I updated my answer with exactly how I solved this similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I think it will be helpful to you.

```
 self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    HomeViewController  * homeview=[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeview];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES:
```

Comment: My code and your code seems to be same in Appdelegate.m could you please point at which I need to change

Answer (score 0):

you need to restructure this line in your code  `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` the reason being when dismiss is called, you loose `self` context of the controller and hence the line   `[self presentModalViewController:startview animated:YES];` is not showing any controller further.
to quicktest just comment dismiss line and see for yourself.

Comment: This makes the login modal view just stay on screen and no changes happen even behind

Answer (score 0):

use this line when your currentViewController DissMiss then try bellow code...

```
[self performSelector:@selector(PresentView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

-(void)PresentView
{
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:startview animated:YES];
}
```

hope,this help you....
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need compatibility with very old iOS versions it is better to use

```
 -(void)presentViewControllerAnimated:completion:
 -(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

instead of

```
 -(void)presentModalViewController:animated:
 -(void)dismissModalViewController:animated:
```

In this case

```
- (void)loginViewController:(LoginViewController *)loginViewController didFinishWithResult:(LoginResult)result 
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
        startview = [[[startViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        [self.presentingViewController presentViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }];
}
```